I'm turning 18 soon, and I don't know how to do anything regarding college applications at all.
I'm sorry for how long, whiny, and pointless this will feel. I have not been able to find anyone aside from therapists to discuss any of this with, and I need advice from people who actually know what I'm asking. (I tried to put the concise questions I need answered below-they are the numbered points)
I was raised by two really awful parents who both failed their med school entrance exams and chose to live vicariously through me. Growing up I was told that being a neurosurgeon was the only feasible career choice- my father's father had parkinson's, and he would tearfully explain how his dead dad would be so sad if i didn't become a doctor. I was told that I would recieve no support if I did not go to medical school. There's way worse that they've done, and way worse i've had to deal with, but i digress. The only reason this matters is that after 15 years of absolute hell the depression I had been fighting with exploded and three years ago, I attempted suicide. For the next three years I fell deeper and deeper into depression. I only got taken seriously when I started failing my classes, after which i was pulled out of highschool. For the last year and a half, while I've been finishing everything I needed to do to graduate and get some sort of college application together my parents have finally shut their mouths and let me figure out what I actually care about. Somehow I pulled through with a 3.92 GPA, which led me to scrap whatever strength i had left in me to take the sat and try and piece together my life and go to college.
But I lost my entire highschool career to depression, and have only starting feeling hope in the last 5 or so months. SAT results came out today, I got a 1550- which made me happy, but I started looking at undergrad programs, and now I'm sad again. My intial plan was to study pure math in undergrad, and go to graduate school and get a phd in something more specific to do with signal processing or acoustics. I've loved making and listening to music since I was a kid, and once I was given space by my parents, I've found that I really like studying signal processing, and sound perception (I'm not sure how to describe this, sorry if my language is incorrect). I did a brief computational neuroscience internship regarding the latter, and I have a decent project proposal to show for it, but I was never able to find the motivation to actually find results. It is very amatuerish, but if you are interested i can send it to you, because I have no objectivity on how much it would actually matter in a college application process. In short, I don't know if this is enough. I wasn't even able to take AP calc BC, which I keep seeing people say pure math majors need to take. I don't even know how to apply to college, and my parents are no help. All I want is to do research. I don't care if it's the worst paying career in the world, because this is the only thing I know how to do. All I've ever been good at is music and math and I would really appreciate some guidance on the following

Is it feasible for me to apply for a pure math undergrad program when my highest level math course is AP Calculus AB?
If I work hard enough will I be able to find a research job somewhere where I can get paid at least enough to live decently? Money is not an issue, I don't care about buying a house or getting a vacation every year or anything. anything at all would be better than how i've spent the last 18 years.
If there is anyone that has any advice or is willing to give me some direction towards schools that might be good to look into,and this process in general I would also appreciate that.I am currently paralyzed with doubt because there is simply too much to sift through and too much i don't understand how to do.

and as if this wasn't mopey enough, footnote-
I also really want to find friends. I've never had a social life, and because of my depression i've never been able to keep friends. are there nice people in this field? or is it sort of like highschool premium, if that doesn't sound like too naive a question?

I know that this is not as concise as soft questions on here usually are, i'd much rather clarify something than have this deleted, though. again I do apologize. And I also want to add that I am not trying to complain, or use my depression as an excuse for any personal shortcomings. I am luckier than most people in many ways, but there are also a lot of things i'm struggling with, i hope you understand.

My highest level high school math course was AP Calculus AB. I graduated college with a pure math degree. So this part is definitely possible.

To bolster Nick Mertes's comment, while I haven't worked in the US specifically, in my experience, universities tend to offer plenty of bridging courses and other opportunities like this. There are courses that will not assume you did well in high school, or dropped out in the final years, and there are often smaller bridging courses that assume even less than this. It may take you a semester or two longer to catch up, but catching up is definitely possible.

Sorry, but this is not the kind of question this website is intended for, and it's not the kind of question this website is good for, so I'm going to vote to close it. The kind of advice you need should come from someone who knows you, not from strangers on the internet. I'd be surprised if your high school didn't have someone whose job is to advise students on how to apply to colleges, and what colleges to apply to; I think that's where you should be going for advice. As for applying for a pure math program, unless things have changed radically since my undergraduate days (continued)

(continued) (which is quite possible, since I entered college in 1968), one doesn't apply for a particular program (in the US; it's different in Australia), one just applies to enter the college, and then one can have as much as a year or even two years to decide on a major.

when my highest level math course is AP Calculus AB? --- Of course! There are rural high schools that do not offer any calculus (AP or other). I attended one such school, and 11-12 years later I taught full-time at another such school. And I have a Ph.D. in math.

I'll preface this as someone who is currently in grad school in the US, who has long suffered with depression and disability. Some of this I picked up along the way, but ultimately this is largely opinionated and should be thought more as a long-form comment. I'm certainly young and naive, and haven't even graduated; I just figured I'd offer my personal take & perspective.

Some of My Background:
So I grew up in a pretty backwaters, impoverished, rural area (poorest county in the state). As in, I didn't have anything better than dial-up internet until after I graduated, the school itself didn't have Wi-Fi until 2013 or so. Most of the students were on free lunch programs and such.
I was able to do some half-baked distance learning thing to do a couple of AP classes (at a substantial cost), one of which was AP Calculus AB. That was the highest math I took in high school.
I applied to a number of places. Was put on too high of a pedestal by my peers and advisors and was fooled into thinking I had a chance at Ivies and whatnot (looking back I can only laugh at the thought - not just for my naivete and being so upset by it, but for thinking it mattered). Ended up getting into a decent state university.
Unlike you, I was originally going down the line of applied math and astrophysics (later on dropped the latter after a few depressing semesters and realizing it didn't click for me): I do like pure math, but there's not really a great program nearby for it, and frankly I mesh better with applied stuff anyways for some weird reason.
Was able to get into a decent grad school as well. Still currently here, about to start Ph.D. work.

What Really Matters?
Something I've learned in this process is that, to some degree, where you go for undergrad doesn't really matter. If you get into the top schools, fine, you're getting a bit better off in terms of resources and "brand recognition". But the education you're getting is not fundamentally that different; perhaps a little more heavyhanded (read: lack of a social life), but most of the math you learn in undergrad wasn't really developed in the past century anyways. At the bottom end you have party schools; obviously avoid those. But everything else vaguely decent in-between, you're probably going to get by just fine in life with.
What typically does matter for undergrad/grad school instead are:

Your advisor for dissertations/theses, somewhat.
The quality of your thesis/dissertation, and how much work/publishing you've done in general. Likewise, projects, internships, whatever you get thrown at you.
The connections you make.

Of course, grades will matter in school as does the knowledge you get as well, but I think those would also be key parts to focus on that not only matter but (unlike course content) could vary from institution to institution.

Social Life:

I also really want to find friends. I've never had a social life, and because of my depression i've never been able to keep friends. are there nice people in this field? or is it sort of like highschool premium, if that doesn't sound like too naive a question?

Much like you, I struggled with a social life in college as well, and frankly regret choices I made in the process. I am very introverted, and am somewhat disabled (I can't drive). And now I'm in grad school, so socializing feels weird when the majority of passersby could be my students. The importance of mental health cannot be understated, and a healthy social life should also be a consideration.
I've met plenty of nice, sociable people in the field. However, I do think that it becomes harder further down the line to form meaningful friendships (e.g. grad school, post-grad). Academics tend to have a bit of a trope of becoming super engrossed in their own work/job and almost neglecting the world around them, and being socially stunted and introverted because of it. Math would be no exception to that rule. Most of my fellow grad TAs almost seem to live in their offices (one maybe even literally?).
Plus, I've had more engaging and interesting and fun conversations about math with my girlfriends and other friends than I have had with fellow academics. (My girlfriend is by no means ignorant to math stuff either, just not as far along as I am with little desire for academia.) This might be because my ultimate passion seems to be math education and explaining math to people, though: talking about math with someone deep in their field or your own is an entirely different experience.
I do think it would be beneficial to surround yourself with some people who aren't so inclined towards math, at least some. A variety of experiences and perspectives can always be nice to have and you don't wanna talk about math day in and day out anyways. :p

Work Prospects:

If I work hard enough will I be able to find a research job somewhere where I can get paid at least enough to live decently? Money is not an issue, I don't care about buying a house or getting a vacation every year or anything. anything at all would be better than how i've spent the last 18 years.

Frankly, the majority of mathematicians end up working in academia, e.g. as professors. This would be less so for applied math (where I lie), but is certainly a trend nonetheless. I don't know exactly where you live / plan to attend / plan to live, but that's something to consider.
Salaries from what I've seen range from the fairly livable to the exorbitant (though my perspective may be skewed, growing up where I did). The median salary for math professors seems to be \$112,000/year (per Salary.com). Salaries for public institutes in the US tend to be publicly viewable, e.g. University of Michigan claims an average of \$107,500, and the lower end for professors/lecturers at about \$60,000. (Note: UM is not my university, just was linked in a Reddit thread here.)
Industry does tend to be the better-paying option where available, since higher education in the US is woefully underfunded and underappreciated (especially with the current political climate). I don't know about the industry prospects for pure math though. (That's not to say they're bad, I just never looked into it.) But:

My intial plan was to study pure math in undergrad, and go to graduate school and get a phd in something more specific to do with signal processing or acoustics. I've loved making and listening to music since I was a kid, and once I was given space by my parents, I've found that I really like studying signal processing, and sound perception (I'm not sure how to describe this, sorry if my language is incorrect).

I will say this feels a lot more like applied math than pure math. You would know your specific interests better than me though. "Pure math" I associate more with items like abstract algebra (the study of mathematical "structure", for lack of a better word), or "math for its own sake, without regard for application." (The line is certainly blurry as hell though.)

Uhh... Final Thoughts, I Guess:

When/if possible, try to seek some sort of academic counseling at your high school. They'll likely be able to redirect you towards more helpful and specific resources than I ever could, especially when it comes to actually doing the application. (I vaguely recall doing my undergrad applications mostly through the Common App. I honestly forget how I did my grad school one, amusingly.)

Honestly, I would also advise you to seek some sort of counseling/therapy in general. (To put it as my GP would: "Honestly, everyone should just be assigned one at age $18$.") Life is hard enough to navigate, and there's clearly a lot you need to parse through when it comes to your familial expectations/treatment of you, and just stress about the future and depression in general. (Not trying to be an armchair psychologist, of course. I just think it might be a good idea. I'm seeking therapy myself. There's no shame in it.)

Perhaps even consider whether you need school / need it right now. A gap year or two might do you a lot of good. (And you can always just study some things in your off-time - there's plenty of free resources online! - or take just a small number of courses at a community college nearby or something.) I feel like (armchair psychologist alarm warning) you may be suffering in part from burnout. I certainly know the "get my crap together" period after almost losing my undergrad scholarship from depression and related reasons contributed to my need for a gap year between undergrad and grad school. Of course, there's a lot to consider if you go down this path (e.g. what will you do for a job in the meantime, how will your family handle it, etc.), so it might be less of an option for you than you'd like.



I wasn't even able to take AP calc BC

So, from what I can see per the College Board website and Wikipedia and what my girlfriend is telling me -- AP Calculus BC is just the same thing as AB, but accelerated so that they cover some (but not all) of the standard topics from Calculus I & II (whereas AB would just be the former). I would argue you're actually better off not taking BC as a result since you'll have more time to get into the weeds in a proper Calculus II course. (Just looking at the primary list of BC topics, compared to when I have taught Calculus II in the past, BC leaves out a good chunk you will want down the road, especially for Calculus III.)



I keep seeing people say pure math majors need to take [AP Calculus AB].

Pure BS, to be honest. Like I said, you'll get the requisite knowledge in undergrad Calculus II anyways. Plenty of math majors, self included, never got anything more than AB or some sort of high school calculus class. A few schools might be the exception to this rule, but they probably have such extreme gatekeeping (e.g. Ivies) that you're ruled out for a thousand other reasons anyways.



Okay I think I've rambled enough. I don't know if you found any of this helpful - honestly, I'm surprised this hasn't been deleted yet like I imagine a lot of these would be - but hopefully I was able to answer some of your questions and give you some semblance of comfort.
You're a smart person. Just sit back and breathe. You'll do fine, I'm sure, especially with how forward thinking you clearly are. You've got this. :)

thank you very much for this response. it was very reassuring and i appreciate how detailed this was. thank you again.

poorest county in the state --- I don't know which state you grew up in, but the high school I said (in a comment to the OP's question) that I taught full-time at for a year is (and was when I was there, and it wasn't a close call) is the only high school in this county. When I was there (June 1988 - Aug 1989) there were NO fast food restaurants in the county (and no dentists, etc.; I lived in a trailer because no other housing) and no movie theaters in the county or in any of the several adjoining counties.
